# ListSerializer and Foreign Key, is_valid doing N+1 query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to improve my serializer to be able to create multiple objects with minimum queries. So I did implement a ListSerializer that will bulk create objects instead of calling save on each objects.

Here my current code:

```
class GatewayTechnicalLogListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    gateway = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.gateways_ids: dict = {}
        for gat_tech_log in self.initial_data:
            self.gateways_ids[gat_tech_log['gateway']] = True
        self.gateways_ids = Gateway.objects.filter(
            id__in=self.gateways_ids.keys()
        ).only('id').values_list('id', flat=True)


    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs.gateway not in self.gateways_ids.keys():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Gateway does not exists.')
        return attrs


    def create(self, validated_data):
        gw_tech_logs_o = [GatewayTechnicalLog(**item) for item in validated_data]
        res = GatewayTechnicalLog.objects.bulk_create(gw_tech_logs_o)
        return res


class GatewayTechnicalLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GatewayTechnicalLog
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = GatewayTechnicalLogListSerializer
```

My problem is now that when the method is_valid is called, it is trying to validate the foreign key gateway for each objects and so fetching the foreign key related.

I'm trying then to remove the validation on that field and validating it myself but it doesn't change anything...

I have not found any example of this, any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's the field name of the foreign key for `Gateway` in your `GatewayTechnicalLog` model? You will have to override the validation for that in `GatewayTechnicalLogSerializer` and not on the list serializer

Comment: Ok, the field name is "gateway", but two question then:
- Do I need to put the validate on the GatewayTechnicalLogSerializer too ?
- How can I manage using my queryset ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up doing, I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it seems to work:

```
class GatewayTechnicalLogListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.gateways_ids: dict = {}
        for gw_tech_log in self.initial_data:
            self.gateways_ids[gw_tech_log['gateway']] = True
        self.gateways_o = Gateway.objects.filter(
            id__in=self.gateways_ids.keys()
        )
        self.gateways_ids = list(self.gateways_o.values_list('id', flat=True))


    def validate(self, attrs):
        # Validating because validation was removed
        for gw_tech_log in attrs:
            if gw_tech_log['gateway'] not in self.gateways_ids:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Gateway does not exists.')
        return attrs


    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Bulk creating and logging after into Azure to improve performance
        gw_tech_logs_o: list = []
        for item in validated_data:
            gateway_id: int = item.pop('gateway')
            item['gateway'] = next(
                gateway_o for gateway_o in self.gateways_o if gateway_o.id == gateway_id
            )
            gw_tech_logs_o.append(GatewayTechnicalLog(**item))
        res = GatewayTechnicalLog.objects.bulk_create(gw_tech_logs_o)
        return res


class GatewayTechnicalLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GatewayTechnicalLog
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = GatewayTechnicalLogListSerializer


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Removing validation on serializer for gateway field
        self.fields['gateway'] = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)


    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # Rolling back changes on field for representation
        self.fields['gateway'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=obj.gateway)
        return super(GatewayTechnicalLogSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been around for a long time, but I had the same problem and I was looking for the solution for several days, in the end I found another solution that worked for me.

I leave it here in case it helps someone, in this way it no longer makes a query for each relationship, now it is only a query for all and in `to_internal_value` it validates the foreign key

```
class GatewayTechnicalLogListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    gateway_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Gateway.objects.all(), source='gateway', write_only=True)
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.gateways_ids = Gateway.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        gateway_id = data.pop('gateway_id', None)

        if gateway_id is not None:
            if not gateway_id in self.gateways_ids:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    'gateway_id': 'Gateway does not exist'
                })
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```